# confuse about User:Group what is the best for /var/www, and Crontab user?

Tags: permissions, cron

I'm new on linux server.

I have 2 question that I'm confuse about this.

1 1. user:group now I chown my /var/www/html like this.

my `nginx.conf` is set `server{ user www-data }`

and in terminal I set

`chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
find /var/www/html/uploads/images -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +`

Is I'm do the right thing ? or it need to set to www-data:www-data ?

2 2. about crontab it a lot of TUT but it is not clear about user who ran crontab. The question is

If I login with `adam` user and my server is own by `root:www-data` or `www-data:www-data` how can I give the crontab to that user not `adam` user ? because it need perm to write the files like backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In general, files in `/var/www` should be owned by `root:www-data` and `chmod 644`, while `/var/www` itself and all subdirectories should be `chmod 755`.

They should *not* be writable by the `www-data` user unless *absolutely necessary* (and that goes triple for executable files) because files which are writable by `www-data` can be modified by an attacker who manages to compromise the web server itself or a script run by the web server (unless you're using `suexec`, in which case they'll have the permissions of the script's owner rather than the web server, which generally isn't much better and may be much worse).  If nothing is writable by `www-data`, then the damage that can be done by an attacker who gains `www-data`'s access is substantially reduced.

2) `cron` jobs are run by the user whose `crontab` invokes the job.  If it's in root's crontab, it runs as root.  If it's in adam's crontab, it runs as adam, etc.

The exception to this is the system-wide crontabs under `/etc` (`/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d/*`, and so on).  The job specification format for these crontabs includes an additional field specifying the user who the job should be run as.

Comment: Thanks you for you answer so if I got this I can run crontab with user that I login to ssh like adam ? on terminal as adam user I can crontab -e to edit my cronjob to backup files and run it as adam user ? so my /var/backup/db is need to chrown to adam:adam and chmod to 644 for the write permission. That right ? (no need to worry about www-data with crontab)

Comment: another way I can edit /etc/cron.d/mycron. But what is the general way ? =-=

Comment: That's correct.  If you ssh in as `adam`, then `crontab -e` will let you set up commands to be run automatically using `adam`'s permissions.

Comment: I think I should `chmod 755` `drwxr-xr-x` to all my folder in www. And `chmod 644` `-rw-r--r--` to all my files in www. That make it secure?

Comment: Oh, yes, directories need execute (`x`) permissions so that the webserver can access files in them. I'll edit my answer to make that more clear. But you figured out the correct settings anyhow.

Comment: Thanks you for you answer again to help me understand :).

Answer (score 0):

(1) `chmod` and `chown` are different commands. The first sets permissions and the second ownership. You may wish to also run

```
`find /var/www/html -exec chown www-data:www-data {} +`
```

in addition to the commands you are already running, but that is a choice for you to make.

(2) You can edit `/etc/cron.allow` and add `www-data` to allow the `www-data` user to run cron jobs. A `man cron` or `man crontab` should give you further info about this if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I think @Dave Sherohman suggest is good thing for security.